# UISearchBar not filtering sqlite UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview, uisearchbar

Hi I have a TableView that is populated by an sqlite database, I've set up a UISearchBar to filter it but it returns no results. Here is my code for the search bar:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text
{
    if(text.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = true;
        entriesFiltered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *queryPart1 = @"SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%";
        NSString *queryPart2 = @"'% ORDER BY name";
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", queryPart1, text, queryPart2];
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {

                char *field2 = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1);
                NSString *field2Str = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:field2];

                NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", field2Str];


                [entriesFiltered addObject:str ];

            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
    }

    [self.theTable reloadData];
}
```

Here is the code for the table view

```
-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    //Return the number of rows in the section
    if(isFiltered){
        return [entriesFiltered count];
    } else {
        return [entries count];
    }


}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Congigure the cell...
    if(isFiltered){
        cell.textLabel.text = [entriesFiltered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = [entries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        return cell;
    }

}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.theTable indexPathForSelectedRow];
   NSLog(@" indexPath row %ld",(long)indexPath.row);
   speakerViewController *svc = [segue destinationViewController];
   svc.labelText = descriptions[indexPath.row];
   svc.url = urls[indexPath.row];

}
```

Is the problem the sql query for searching? Would it be better to just search the array instead of querying the database? if so how would i do this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I would fetch the results to memory and use them after if they were a relatively small set. 
If you really want to do it in the query, check the query! 
I don't get why you do SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '% ..?
That should be SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE ? and than you pass the argument to sql, or then SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%@' to be substituted by the other string. Another thing, have you checked if predicates are allowed?

Comment: you do entriesFiltered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];. does the tableview have this same ( new ) reference to entries filtered? If they aren't in the same scope it would need to have its reference updated.

Comment: both arrays are populated in methods outside of the table view methods and the tableview works with the entries array, why would it need a new reference?

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto surely i need to do SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%searchtext%' as i need to use % as the sql wildcard?

Comment: @Will, sorry, didn't really got your question ...
But, btw, have you tried to NSLog the final query?

Comment: @AfonsoTsukamoto just tried that and now i feel a bit stupid! it was a ' in the wrong place, I had '% in queryPart2 and should've been %'. Thanks for your help

Comment: Ahah! Cool! Glad to help! And don't feel stupid, I can't talk by everyone in SO, but a lot of us have questions and problems just like that.